# How to allow iframe to access Element.prototype

Tags: javascript

I have created prototypes such as `hasClass()` so i can call `e.target.hasClass('className');`. Now, when i call the prototype it works, however I have an iframe on my page which I go in and out of all the time as I am working on a page builder. However, if I am referring to an element within the iframe the prototype function doesn't exist to the element.

How can I get the `Element.prototype` functions to work within both the parent and the iframe?

Comment: Use load event of iframe to assign same prototype properties inside each frame window

Comment: How would i go about that, i have an onload event on the iframe but nothing more.

Comment: Ah you mean to put the prototype definitions within the onload function.

Comment: Is it not possible to extend the Element and pass the iframe to it to bind the prototype?

Comment: yes in onload, and define them the same way you do in main page

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me :/

Comment: Without providing any code not much anyone can do to help

Comment: Well i was attempting to do var win = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument; Then do win.Element.prototype but that gives Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined. I tried just defining them normally as Element.prototype after the onload but this didnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the iframe window inside a load event handler and can do something like the following:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('ifrm');
frame.onload = function() {
  var win = this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument;
  win.Element.prototype.test = function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'Iframe Prototype content'
  }
  win.document.getElementById('heading').test()

}
```

So if you were to wrap all your new prototype properties into a function you could call that in both the main window context and the frame window context

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/goPtyz2fLNvKNgN7knU5?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this. I do have a quick question. This works for me nicely, but if i create an element dynamically the function then doesn't work for the dynamic element is there some thing i can create that looks for new elements and when created it automatically assigns the protoype to it?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work if element is in the dom. The window.Element hasn't changed. Update demo to reproduce problem

Comment: Ah, no i noticed the problem as soon as i sent this. Most of my prototypes work correctly. One of them isn't and it's because i am using querySelectorAll which obviously isnt an individual element. Was simply a mistype on my behalf. I apologise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok but each element in that collection should be fne

Answer (score 0):

Each window has its own Element object. You need to add your function to the prototype of the Element belonging to the iframe as well as the parent frame's.

---

Alternatively, don't add your own function. Use [the standard one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
e.target.classList.contains("className");
```